# Como verificar o tamanho de um array do tipo PFA?

Tags: java, array, java-processing

Como eu faço para verificar se o *array* PFA (Partially-full array) está cheio e novos elementos não poderão ser adicionados? Se ele estiver cheio, deve retornar `true`.

```
boolean estaCheio(int[] data, int size){
       ??? }
```

Tenho 5 possíveis opções. Acredito que a opção A retorna `true`se o *array* estiver cheio. Está correto?

```
a) return size == data.length;
b)return size == data.length-1;
c)return size <= data.length;
d)return size <= data.length-1;
e)return size < data.length;
```

Se eu criar uma função inserir, essa função vai dar erro se a lista estiver cheia. Como a função acima `staCheio()` poderia prevenir isso?

```
int insert(int[] data, int size, int newData){
   if( ??? )
      data[size++] = newData;
   return size;
  }
```

Qual dessas opções devo usar? Acredito que seja a opção C. Está correto?

```
a)!isFull(data, size+1)
b)isFull(data, size+1)
c)!isFull(data, size)
d)isFull(data, size)
e)!isFull(data, size-1)
```

Para testar o código acima eu uso esse código:

```
void setup(){
  int MAX_SIZE = 4;
  int[] numbers = new int[MAX_SIZE];
  int howMany = 0;

  howMany = insert(numbers,howMany,34);
  howMany = insert(numbers,howMany,99);
  howMany = insert(numbers,howMany,14);
  howMany = insert(numbers,howMany,22);
// howMany = insert(numbers,howMany,50);
  int newSize = insert(numbers, howMany, 57);
  if( newSize == howMany )
      println("Insert failed!! " + newSize);
  howMany = newSize;

  delete(numbers, newSize);


 // howMany = insert(numbers,howMany,50);
  printAll(numbers,howMany);
  println (isFull (numbers,howMany));
}

void printAll(int[] data, int size){
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    print(data[i]+"  ");
  println();
}


 int insert(int[] data, int size, int newData){
   if( !isFull(data, size) )
      data[size++] = newData;
   return size;

}

boolean isFull(int[] data, int size){
       return size == data.length;
     }


      int delete(int[] data, int size){
    if(size>0){
      for( int i=1; i<size; i++ )
        data[i-1]=data[i];
      size--;
    }//if
    return size;
  }
```

Comment: Você viu no [tour] que você pode votar em tudo no site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As duas opções estão corretas, dentro da lógica normal seria isto, apesar de eu achar que o código está ruim.